# What exatcly is a ListenableFuture<> ,what it does and when to use it

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, google-api

I found this class: ListenableFuture<>.

I've understood something, but i dont think my understanding is correct. So I would like to ask if someone could explain better. My understanding is: It is a class to perform some asynchronus tasks that can produce output or fail. For example it is  theoretically same as if statement. If  true do this, else do this. But the if statement runs on main thread so the other code is not being executed until if statement is finished. So in this case if you want to perform a task and you need to use its output without blocking the main thread, let's say listenable future is doing his task while main thread is going on. Once the listenable future finished his job, then it throws a callback that can be registered in main thread. Is that somehow correct? I know i made some confusion but my english is not perfect. Still i find listenable future confusing to me. Could you make some examples? or explain better what it is and when to use? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ListenableFuture` is an extension of `Future` that allows you to register one or more "callback" functions to be notified when the Future is completed.

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained

It's not part of Android, it's provided by Guava...
https://developer.android.com/guide/background/asynchronous/listenablefuture

...But the "Listenable Future Explained" article that I linked above strongly suggests that you use it, rather than `Future`, in new Android apps.